# Set input as invalid

Tags: jquery, validation

I have two inputs, e.g.

```html
pass:       <input type="password" name="pass" required/>
pass again:  <input type="password" name="pass2" required/>
```

and I want to compare these inputs, and if they match, set input as valid. I tried this, but I think that `prop('valid', true);` does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=pass2]').keyup(function() {
        if($('input[name=pass]').val() == $('input[name=pass2]').val()) {
            $('#pass_hint').empty();
            $('#pass_hint').html('match');
            $(this).prop('valid', true);
        } else {
            $('#pass_hint').empty();
            $('#pass_hint').html('mismatch');
            $(this).prop('invalid', true);
        }
    });
});
```

I create a registration form and if passwords are not the same, input field is invalid and I can´t submit this and show me some hint. ...and I don´t know how I set this input as invalid

Comment: Do you expect some sort of different behavior when you mark it as invalid, or do you just expect the style to indicate to the user that it's invalid?

Comment: Does you login box actually include a displayed element called `#pass_hint`? PS. you don't have to empty it, `.html()` does that for you.

Comment: Actually, why are you validating user input in JQuery? It is manipulatable and the user will be easily able to bypass these rules.
I suggest doing it on the server side.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: Yes, server-side validation is absolutely necessary. But client-side validation is also nice so the user doesn't have to wait for a request to the server to find out they messed something up.

Comment: i create a registration form and if passwords are not the same, input field is invalid and i don´t submit this and show me some hint.
...and i don´t know how i set this input as invalid

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the [HTMLInputElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), there is no such property as `valid` or `invalid`.

You can use the [`setCustomValidity(error)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441292.aspx) method with native form validation.

As for your script, here's a demo that should work in all HTML5 compliant browsers:

```js
$('input[name=pass2]').keyup(function () {
    'use strict';

    if ($('input[name=pass]').val() === $(this).val()) {
        $('#pass_hint').html('match');
        this.setCustomValidity('');
    } else {
        $('#pass_hint').html('mismatch');
        this.setCustomValidity('Passwords must match');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='#'>
    <p>Password:
        <input name=pass type=password required>
    </p>
    <p>Verify:
        <input name=pass2 type=password required>
    </p>
    <p id=pass_hint></p>
    <button type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I assume Chrome is an HTML 5 Compliant browser, yet your fiddle doesn't work

Comment: @SerjSagan I just tested it in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 on Linux and it works. Can you elaborate on what is not working?

Comment: My bad. Didn't look at the code long enough to see that you had to type at least something in that second field in order for the validation to kick in, nm

Comment: Is this answer out of date? [W3Schools has a page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_invalid.asp) on the input:invalid property.

Comment: @PatPeter that's a CSS selector, not a property on a DOM element.