# Remove input:invalid in other link click + HTML5

Tags: html

I'm using HTML5 field validation for controls input type = "number" , "email". On Submit red outline for this controls are coming since its a required field. But while clearing control values I want to remove this red border also. Any pointers will be helpful. I have tried  $("#txtName").removeClass('invalid'); but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#txtName").removeClass('invalid')` would work if you have a custom CSS class (`.invalid`) which you **added** yourself upon form validation (for example, with `$("#txtName").addClass('invalid')`).

If you're using *built-in* form validation (i.e. with `<input type="..." required>`), you should see
the answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128882/set-input-as-invalid), specifically the `setCustomValidity(error)` method.