# Can I Set Some HTML5 Validation With JQuery In A Certain Way?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, validation

So I have a `textarea` in my form that has a `minlength="15"` and `maxlength="2000"`. But this means that when the user reaches 2000 characters, he can type no more. What I want is the user to have the ability to type ever more character, but use client-side validation, on submit, to check if the `textarea` value is valid. If not, I want to make it invalid, and show the default HTML5 validation bubble. Here is my code so far:

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

#charLeft {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea placeholder="Describe Your Issue*" aria-placeholder="Describe Your Issue" name="describeIssue" id="describeIssue" class="describeIssue" onkeyup="countChar(this)" minlength="15" maxlength="2000" required></textarea>

    <div id="charLeft">0/15</div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function countChar(val) {
      let length = val.value.length;

      if (length > 15 && length < 2000) {
        $('#charLeft').html(length + '/2000');
        $('#charLeft').css('color', '#27ae60');
      } else if (length < 15) {
        $('#charLeft').html(length + '/15');
        $('#charLeft').css('color', '#e74c3c');
      } else {
        $('#charLeft').html(length + '/2000');
        $('#charLeft').css('color', '#e74c3c');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

As seen above, if you get to the limit of 2000 characters, the `textarea` won't allow any more. I want it that it will go past 2000 characters, but when you submit, and if it is past 2000 characters, mark it invalid. I am not sure how to do that, so that is where I would need some assistance. I can accept plain JavaScript or JQuery. Thanks in advance, and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML, remove the maxlength property. This will allow users to type more then 2000 characters. In the JS, add a submit handler that checks, like so:

```js
function countChar(val) {
  let length = val.value.length;

  if (length > 15 && length < 2000) {
    $('#charLeft').html(length + '/2000');
    $('#charLeft').css('color', '#27ae60');
  } else if (length < 15) {
    $('#charLeft').html(length + '/15');
    $('#charLeft').css('color', '#e74c3c');
  } else {
    $('#charLeft').html(length + '/2000');
    $('#charLeft').css('color', '#e74c3c');
  }
}

$("form").submit((e) => {

  var val = $("#describeIssue").val();
  if (parseInt(val.length) > 2000) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("To Long!");
  } else {
    //the user passed the lenghth
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

#charLeft {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <textarea placeholder="Describe Your Issue*" aria-placeholder="Describe Your Issue" name="describeIssue" id="describeIssue" class="describeIssue" onkeyup="countChar(this)" minlength="15" required></textarea>

  <div id="charLeft">0/15</div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This code allows the user to type more than 2000 characters, but they cannot submit the input if it has a problem (goes over the length).

Comment: Thanks! The only issue here is that I want to find a way to see if you can tell the form that this `textarea` is invalid, and therefore, it will do the normal `invalid` operator. If it is not possible, no worries. I'll still accept this answer!

Comment: Here is a link that could help with that: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128882/set-input-as-invalid/18129355)
@JasonD'Silva

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the user to type more than 2000 characters and then return a custom error message, but you can't do that and show the default HTML5 error. To achieve the former, remove `maxlength="2000"` and add an `onsubmit` listener to the form, in which you will check whether the length of the text has exceeded 2000 characters, then decide to submit the form or not.

```js
function countChar(val) {
  let length = val.value.length;

  if (length > 15 && length < 2000) {
    $('#charLeft').html(length + '/2000');
    $('#charLeft').css('color', '#27ae60');
  } else if (length < 15) {
    $('#charLeft').html(length + '/15');
    $('#charLeft').css('color', '#e74c3c');
  } else {
    $('#charLeft').html(length + '/2000');
    $('#charLeft').css('color', '#e74c3c');
  }
}

$('#describeIssue').on('submit', function(event) {
  if ($('#describeIssue').value.length > 2000) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

#charLeft {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <textarea placeholder="Describe Your Issue*" aria-placeholder="Describe Your Issue" name="describeIssue" id="describeIssue" class="describeIssue" onkeyup="countChar(this)" minlength="15" required></textarea>

  <div id="charLeft">0/15</div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```